# Jelastic or Cloudbees support for websockets

Tags: websocket, railo, cloudbees, jelastic

Does anyone know if it's possible to use websockets on Cloudbees or Jelastic.  I deployed a Railo project with websockets on port 10126, it works beautifully on my Tomcat local setup however nothing happens when deployed to both Jelastic and Cloudbees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Jelastic we do. That is one of the outcomes of our making Public IPs available. We will be doing a short how-to article coming up this very topic. You can look out for it on our blog (http://blog.jelastic.com) or our twitter account (@jelastic).

Comment: that will be very helpful but I need to do a demo Friday and it's not working, can you tell me how to get this working

Comment: Were you able to get it running? (I didn't get a notification that you responded to me).

I tried it a few times with different setups and had no problems, it was just a question of turning on the public IP and then going about it as normal.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudbees now supports Websockets.

This is done via a proxy - so can work with any app via http upgrade.

simply set:

bees app:proxy:update http_version=1.1

as http 1.1 support Upgrade to websocket (thus ws and wss will work).

Comment: For some applications, websockets procure significant advantages, the question was not why and when should we use websockets over Comet, the question was which host provides websocket support... (assuming the question author does indeed have a good reason to use websockets)

Answer (score 1):

CloudBees now offers support for WebSockets - you just need to use a different endpoint to access your application: http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/WebSockets

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, only [dotCloud](http://dotcloud.com) supports websockets for now: http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/websockets/

Comment: I'll give it a try but all these cloudservices have their own way of deployment.  Hopefully it's not to painful to setup

Comment: If it is of any help, here my app (in Java Play!): https://github.com/Ekito/MapTracker/tree/dotcloud

Answer (score 0):

Ok in my understanding with Jelastic they support running Websockets in GlassFish and can support Public IPs.

while Cloudbees supports running separate JVMs (plain java apps, no app server) but without Public IPs.

Here are some references:

[Cloudbees JVM container](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container)